# ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query returns BigDecimal

Tags: ruby, activerecord, configuration, connection

I need to call a procedure in my ruby rest api in Sinatra and I'm calling it like:

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query query
```

After that I'm parsing it to hash:

```
results = results.to_hash
```

My procedure already have it's number format and returns all the numbers like `92.00`. But in the results I have it parsed as a BigDecimal. And when I'm returning this to my client like:

```
JSON.pretty_generate(results)
```

It is returned as `92.0`. I have a lot developed already and searched everywhere a way to make ActiveRecord respect the number format that my SQL query returned, but couldn't find anywhere. Do you guys have a configure solution or a different approach for pure SQL queries on ruby without rails?

EDIT:

To solve it for a while I made the code below, but I can't accept this as an answer for this problem:

```
  def self.format_hash_results(results)
    rresults = results
    rresults.each do |row|
      row.each do |k,v|
        row[k] = '%.2f' % v if v.class == BigDecimal
      end
    end
    rresults
  end
```

Comment: JSON is just an encoding method. Why not handle the formatting in the application receiving the JSON data? Passing in numbers as strings is kind of annoying.

Comment: It's an api, 3 different applications are using. I'm trying to pattern that

Comment: That's all the more reason to respect the JSON format and send regular numbers, not stringified numbers. If presentation is a problem, handle it if/when the numbers are displayed, not when they're packaged for transport. Unless someone's going to be looking at your raw JSON payload and complaining about decimal places, this is a non-issue. What you might want to do is communicate your payload like this: `{ "value": 92.0, "precision": 2 }`

Comment: That's a very good point. The presentation is responsibility of the view... Thanks for that. I'll rearrange things over here! Thank you very much!